# Scalar functions with UniVerse ODBC driver

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, odbc, universe

I am using the UniVerse ODBC driver to pull data from our transactional system to SQL Server 2008. The ODBC driver is installed on Windows Server 2003 and it works fine. I am trying to find some help on the syntax for writing the scalar functions such as CONVERT.

As I went through the manual, I found that the function is supported. But when I try to write a query like

```
SELECT CONVERT(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM TableName
```

the query fails with syntax error. I am suspecting that the ODBC driver does not support this syntax. Any help with this will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to format your scalar functions like so:

```
{fn CONVERT(EXAMPLEFIELD, SQL_VARCHAR )}
```

Therefore, your completed query may look like:

```
SELECT {fn CONVERT(ID, SQL_VARCHAR )} FROM TableName
```

I tested a similar query through my ODBC connection to Universe and it did not result in a syntax error.

I found the following article from Microsoft about ODBC explicit conversions to be helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms715381(v=vs.85).aspx